# post запрос, проблема с отправкой нужных данных

Tags: php

// есть x кнопок, при нажатии button x нужно отправить button x value , но 
 // при этом в браузере все кнопки должны выводиться одним названием, например Y

```
<?php 
 while($result2=mysqli_fetch_array($data2))
        {
            $sub=$result2['name'];
            $clas=$result2['classid'];
        echo "<option value='" . $id ."'>" . $sub ."</option>";
        // echo "<input name = \"DZ2\" type = \"hidden\" value = \"$clas\" />";
             echo "<input id = \"DZ\" name= \"$clas\" type = \"submit\" value = \"$clas\" />";
?>
```

[image: КАК ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ][image: КАК СЕЙЧАС, ЧТОБ В POST ПЕРЕДАВАЛОСЬ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ КНОПКИ]

Answer (score 0):

сам разобрался, может кому надо будет $i=name кнопки которую нажал, в name записывал выбранную кнопку, так как value кнопок нужно на странице выводить одинаковые а функции под кнопками разные, количество кнопок должно по условию быть случайное

```
 <?php
    $city = $_POST;
    $array[] = $city;
    //print_r($array);
    //echo $array[0][2];
     for ($i = 0; $i <=1000; $i++) 
      { 
        if(isset($array[0][$i]))
        {
            echo $i;
            break;
        }
      } 
    ?>
```